# Java Applet with database

Tags: java, jdbc, applet

I'm trying to write a simple Applet which must get text data from database.

I have some problems:

- I have remote mysql db or i can create a local db, what would be the
  most correct?
- I have downloaded mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar and put it to
  my applet source directory

  yakoot@yakoot-home:~/java$ echo $CLASSPATH
  /home/yakoot/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar

but when I try,

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

I see

> error: unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or
>   declared to be thrown

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

I tried some different locations for mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar, but it did not help

Comment: It's a compile-time error. It says, you must enclose that statement within a `try...catch` block and catch/handle the `ClassNotFoundException` in case it's thrown.

Comment: a local or remote db thats upto your requirement bro.

Comment: i know it, but if i enclose this within a try-catch i see no errors and it's not working

Comment: I do this not for me.. Will the connection to the database work correctly on another machine without any additional actions?

Comment: i'm done this applet, synchronize my project folder via ubuntuone with my work machine, but when i'm trying to run applet at work it can it can not load com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.. connection in services tab work finely, CLASS_PATH = path to driver from services connection properties.. whats wrong?

Comment: the problem is solved, it was required to add connector to libraries in netbeans project properties..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your MySQL JAR File in Class Folder Instead. i.e. if you are using netbeans you need to choose include library/JAR Folder. then browse mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar file.
Then rebuild the source and run again.

Comment: Hmm.. I dont use netbeans or other ide.. but i'll try tomorrow, thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can have local or remote db as your requirement is.

Second you need to enclose `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` in a try catch block.

```
try
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks sir, actually I have been using my phone to reply lately and this "auto capitalization" :-D , but yea i should have taken care. Thank you for helping me improve it

Comment: @AndrewThompson haha..:-D , thank you sir , and yea thats surely a better implementation. Thank you. :-)

Comment: Cool.  That's some noise deleted and (wipes hands together in finality) ..my work here is done.  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson hahah..cool.. We have like crashed together on quite some posts, i have seen your responses. RESPECT you as a co member. :-) (y)